# How do I create my own SDK and make it usable in little integration code in appDelegeate for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sdk, parse-platform

What I want and need is this:

I wrote a lot of code that gathers lots of data and I got my own server where I hold my data in.

How do I create a SDK and make third party users take my SDK and copy-paste in their Xcode build and like write a sample code in their app delegate to compile all my code and send these data to my server?

For example:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"EOsdNvdE9TXKTZ4ZNF6zRrCpn0SFCaO6aisrbUfM"
                  clientKey:@"z2oW1TzNFyAcyK8wsNDaqgJZjXOzEQzTnI8GnD89"];
```

Parse make their users write a unique code in their app delegate.

How can I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Create project as a `static library` and define public interface. 
Developers will able to import your static lib as xxx.a file and headers you've defined.

[Static library tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

So all you need:

- static library project
- define public headers
- build static library project
- import static library and headers to YOUR_APP
- in YOUR_APP use your library through your header f.e PrefixParse.h

I'd recommend to use some prefix for your lib in order to avoid conflicts with other 3rd party code!